# Typescript overloaded Optional Parameter in two functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a resolver function which might have an optional second parameter called otherParams. I would like that Typescript checks if the function returned from createResourceThunk is also called with the parameter otherParams if it is defined in the resolver function.
How can I do that?
Minimal reproducable example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ArgJwMYQILuAS0QDt4AeAFQD4oBeKAQ0JAChRIoBhOgGy4CM70Aa1KUa9Ri3DQAInnhg6wdAAsxDZpLZYAJtoBCEYAHcIEQiQCSAGihkoEAB7Az2%20FGSFBhREcIBtAF0bAFV7Jxc3Dy8ffwCqWj8AOmSyG2soZMTggKYmRzBEVGAoADMPXAJCKHRUCEUIOCQ0TDJlKPIbAAU6VDoAW3gbAHlgZQhUbt6Bmyww50JXKD8FKfgALihJ-vgAqAAfJZXtja3pqERR8dP1qBGxiZ7tuIAKJih6CqIbxpQMbE-iOQKFY3lBakguAA3cYbZ6ZHoAcxuWAAlDQqJ1UIg%20nIIECmGiAN6ggD0JKgAAFgPAALR4BHeWqg2rANBVMqEAFQOHJRHI3QGYymcycHj8IQiYFLLB%20AAMASC0r8AEYFRQiaD3ugvsVlo8zuhuHwBMIbBd7tddrQ%20QBuTVgwxs%20jwECc7naOQKJTKDayeSKFRo6hUYnvMNQD3%2073PAT4L6JeDAHrAHBxwjPFEou3h97AVAgKChnNanURxR0NRGOh4YrgxBQ8bPI5nc1XfXwLP28ORr0qGMA%20AJ5DoTDweCpyrPQllpNQAC%20mezxeqRvFwigADINyuxSbB0QAMrD0duLc740SxKH48IeBTmcVhdL8Nzlfe7njLGoDXLiOegPKP2aaDp%20hQTkQ96gag86Ll2YaGruEqbtuCEXsIV6EAAoqgX7Ieea77lhOGFJBxHQU%20cFzvac5LjRTBUbkZJQEYNaqEMYBptwpxMNqxDFBy6DKmINR1M4PzNBArRRM8ADk6gyTYMYbISdAbIQyB9Lw4xzjYvAbImqB4IQCJBhiWI4vAECJHWDayfJmZMGS2o4RAuBMAJypTqpUDKjphbwDeY7gYQsKmYWc5%20TJSB9AgeZGQiMkooxJIWfA8VQKMeCoNoUDNu55SeSpGy%20TYhIBSOt7BaF6LhQuuSOeSLGjCgxTsZxXDcbxialOUABMwm1PU4l-FJnh2YwCnct5RVQOpmnaWFmLYri1kIPW0LjSAiVJUx8DKCgXA5Vp1SFLUbkCb1XnFX5ZWBeOALVcGtVJQ1wCIFAfTqPQqAIhpZjUvlnKXTNJX%20XdVXcmFhIRTYUXYrFhnGYlQA)

```
export function createResourceThunk<T, Params, A, OtherParams extends A | never>(
  actions: ResourceActions<T>,
  resolver: (params: Params, otherParams: OtherParams) => Promise<T>
) {
  return function(params: Params, callbacks: Callbacks<T>, otherParams: OtherParams) {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      dispatch(actions.startAction());
      try {
        const data = await (otherParams ? resolver(params, otherParams) : resolver(params));
        ...
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    };
  };
}
```

Currently it is expecting always a third Parameter in the call of the returned function

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playgound](https://tsplay.dev/yNag9W) where others can demonstrate your issue (and only your issue) for themselves.  It is much easier to help if I can start from your problem instead of having to re-create your problem.

Comment: What are you doing with `A | never`?  That is immediately reduced to `A` no matter what.  Also, in your [mcve] I'd suggest showing a few use cases of calling `createResourceThunk()` and calling what it returns, with `resolver` parameters that do / do not take a second parameter, so that folks can demonstrate what's supposed to be happening.  Otherwise you will get the answer "just make `otherParams` optional everywhere with a `?`".

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/BmxAbW) work for your use cases?  If not, please elaborate, preferably with a [mcve] that shows what you need.  (Hmm, have I mentioned that you should provide a [mcve]?  Is there an echo in here? )

Comment: @jcalz Haha, your are absolutely right with the echo and also that I should have created a minimal r.e. I'll add it to the question. Thank you pointing to the typescript playground for this

Comment: Btw. the type AddBetween is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985074/typescript-how-to-add-an-item-to-a-tuple

Comment: Please edit the code in the text of the question to reflect what's going on in your [mcve]; I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code in your linked example, I'd be inclined to use the following typing:

```
export function createResourceThunk<T, P, O extends [] | [otherParams: any]>(
  actions: ResourceActions<T>,
  resolver: (params: P, ...args: O) => Promise<T>
) {

  return function (params: P, callbacks: Callbacks<T>, ...otherParamsArr: O) {
    const [otherParams] = otherParamsArr; // if you care
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      dispatch(actions.startAction());
      try {
        const data = await resolver(params, ...otherParamsArr);
        dispatch(actions.successAction({ data }));
        callbacks && callbacks.onSuccess && callbacks.onSuccess({ data });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(actions.errorAction({ error }));
        callbacks && callbacks.onError && callbacks.onError({ error });
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The important piece here is that the "optional" second parameter is represented as a rest argument, whose type is a *union* of [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) types.  The type parameter `O` is the *list* of parameters after the `params` argument.  It is constrained to either have zero elements (`[]`) or one element (`[otherParams: any]`).  So anywhere before where you'd want to say `otherParams` you would use a rest parameter like `...otherParamsArr`.

That works inside the implementation with no errors or type assertions necessary.  You can verify that this also works from the caller's side:

```
// with OptionalParam
const func1 = createResourceThunk('any', (a: { a: number }, b: string) => Promise.resolve('any'))
func1({ a: 1 }, { successAction: () => { } }, 'somestring') // okay
func1({ a: 1 }, { successAction: () => { } }); // error

// without OptionalParam
const func2 = createResourceThunk('any', (a: { a: number }) => Promise.resolve('any'))
func2({ a: 1 }, { successAction: () => { } }) // okay
func2({ a: 1 }, { successAction: () => { } }, 'somestring') // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ArgJwMYQILuAS0QDt4AeAFQD4oBeKAQ0JAChRIoBhOgGy4CM70Aa1KUa9Ri3DQAInnhg6wdAAsxDZkwgAPMIlTAoAM2SFcBQlHSoIiiHCRpMZZScHkANFAAKngPJRtYAhCABN4KABtAF0oAB9IxGBlCFQvOlQ6AFt4AC5xECiKAAomKHozIlzYBBQMbAricgp3UqhrJC4ANxS8ooUM7LyfKAA6MfSAcyrfAEoaKi9UREy5CCamOYBvJlbrYDQLY1N8Iig+9Kyq4fRuPgFhPM4efiERZtGxxOTUi+ysVFQeVmUG2ZTK6EqBgiXxSaQG8BitBhP3h-1QAG4oAB6LFQPCGKAgFCWdIQVplPYHejwECmM4hOQKJTKPKyeSKFRzahUUFgsoM9nMooCE7EEbwYDpYA4UVFGYzdHksHAVAgEFKvkQ4gGEKKOhqADudDwBnaiC6KXO8M8YxGyLhlzRCo1YIFTJUwoa8HFyHQmHg8Bl5iKmyguslUAAvvLFXzNbcXsIoAAyZMk573b1EADKvv94VT6burzthFzfoQ8BDYb1UedcajJOZZxSS1QWxd-MZHOUntF3tbeiDRGrg9QdfrDaLiYLaZuGZLRAAogC9Cm5wnM6WV23R6vx9HY3HI0rI0eTyedkwcVADSbVL4wKLuA7MkwtRKjCZ0ABGMRWGwgnsWonBcQhBCKABydRIM8YU8lDOg8kIZBMl4FIo08Xg8glVA8EICYuQWJYVngCARjNC0oJg+UmCOX9qyQqA-0jTxQ3gPNK2HQheiIkFG1YqBIKQTIEBVfCJkguYb0QQQ6GYeif0YvIWLYqAOIrANuN4+Z+MjOtMRvMcdhvO8khQAxH2fLhX3fSEv1MAAmf9rFsYDHAgZxXGoxhYLOJjEOQ1D0IPPjFmWVYKJqKjoN82j6Mc5TmMw-iNPzbSzj40N9OjbFcVk+S6O-RLAuSwT2M4rSGh07k9JS4TljEvCCKkvKAn3IA)

Comment: Thx for your help. It does a wonderful job

Comment: Hi @jcalz, hope your doing well. I have another interesting question regarding typescript and maybe you've got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69264949